# Stderr: kinit: Client - not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials

Tags: python, docker, kerberos, impala

I have set up a python docker image and included a krb5.conf file, keytab file, and python libraries.  I am running a python script that authenticates to a kerborized hadoop cluster.  I am running into the error: `Stderr: kinit: Client 'root@MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL' not found in Kerberos database while getting initial credentials.`  I dont know why it is failing on the client `root` when I set up `svc_account`. Do I need to add something to this krb5.conf file or something like this?

The following is my python code:

```
import ssl
from impala.dbapi import connect
import os

os.system("kinit")
conn = connect(host='impala/server2primary.my.domain.local@MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL', port=21050, use_ssl=True, user='svc_account@MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL',  auth_mechanism = 'GSSAPI')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SHOW DATABASES;')
result=cur.fetchall()
for data in result:
    print (data)
```

I have set up the `krb5.keytab` file:

```
addent -password -p svc_account@MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL -k 1 -e rc4-hmac
addent -password -p svc_account@MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL -k 1 -e aes256-cts
addent -password -p svc_account@MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL -k 1 -e aes128-cts
wkt /etc/krb5.keytab
```

The following is my `krb5.conf` file:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL
dns_lookup_kdc = false
dns_lookup_realm = false
ticket_lifetime = 86400
renew_lifetime = 604800
forwardable = true
default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac
default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac
permitted_enctypes = aes256-cts aes128-cts rc4-hmac
udp_preference_limit = 1
kdc_timeout = 3000

[realms]
MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL = {
kdc = server1primary.my.domain.local
admin_server = server1primary.my.domain.local
default_domain = MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL
}

[domain_realm]
MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL = MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL
```

Comment: Did you read the `man` page for _kinit_ ?!?!?

Comment: Yes, so do you think I should try os.system(“kinit -t krb5.keytab”) am I close? @Samson Scharfrichter

Comment: `kinit -kt  /blah/blah/my-app.keytab my-app-account@MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL`

Comment: This was my first experience with this kind of stuff.  It was a success, thank you very much for your help. @Samson Scharfrichter

Comment: _[typo edited]_ And DO NOT dump your application-specific creds into `/etc/krb5.keytab` which is used by security services such as SSSD to "bind" to external authentication/authorization systems... and which should be accessible to _root_ only

Comment: I am not familiar with python syntax, but in general, this issue occurs when the given user principal(service account id) and/or password is incorrect. Underlying error is "Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)" - means KDC fails to find given principal in AD.
Try kinit with keytab as suggested by Samson. If whatever information present in keytab is correct, then you should receive the ticket. Otherwise try generating new keytab.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @BhushanKarmarkar I have already solved my problem with Samson’s answer, but I appreciate what you added, as this information is valuable in my learning experience due to me being new at integrations and authentication with Kerberos environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following fixed my issue:

```
os.system("kinit -kt /etc/krb5.keytab svc_account@MY.DOMAIN.LOCAL")
```